# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/table/types/logical/LogicalTypeRoot

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-table-api

I am trying to read parquet files via the **ParquetAvroInputFormat** but it throws *NoClassDefFoundError* exceptions. I find the class in the **flink-table-common** library.

It is in the path
`org.apache.flink.table.types.logical.LogicalTypeRoot` but the `org.apache.flink.table` and after that seems could not be found.

It is a Scala project, **flink-table-api-scala-bridge** is also included.

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different Java versions caused the problem.

Project Structure used Azul 13, while the application used Java 11 corretto.